# How to output the most common value in a range of Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I use a column to track the day votes from various surveys, and I'd like to find the date that has received the most votes among a range of dates. For instance:

| Name | 20-Oct | 21-Oct | 22-Oct | 23-Oct | 24-Oct |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| B | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | No |
| C | No | Yes | No | Yes | Yes |
| D | Yes | No | Yes | Yes | Yes |
| E | No | Yes | Yes | Yes | Yes |

Can it be done in Google Spreadsheets?

I tried using QUERY to do some work around, but I got no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the table in the example starting at A1 in the sheet:

```
=let(
dates,B1:F1,
votes,B2:F6,
yesperday,bycol(votes,lambda(each,countif(each,"Yes"))),
filter(dates,yesperday=max(yesperday)))
```